# InputBox Numeric validation in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, validation

I've used inputbox in my vb.net2008 application to accept quantity for a particular product, I want to give numeric validation for this inputbox. The characters(a-z) must not be able to entered in this input box, the same that we do on a textbox_keypress event. Please help

Comment: Are you asking about winform or web form

Comment: @Vighnesh Kumar: Windows form

Comment: Have you considered creating your own usercontrol or function to mimic the inputbox? In my opinion, the default inputbox looks very unprofessional.

Comment: As chris said, the InputBox is as far as I know one of the legacy VB6 relics like MsgBox. It's ill advised to use them in almost all cases. You will be much better off if you Make a small class for this on your own since it shouldn't be much work and can be fully customized to fit in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out...

http://www.functionx.com/vb/functions/inputbox.htm

Just what I thought. It says the inputbox does not have filtering events that you can subscribe to. So my suggestion, you have 2 options... Either create your own input box and subscribe to the textbox keypress event to filter data or have the user enter data into the inputbox first and validate data after it's entered, if you insist on using the inputbox. These are your only options.

Answer (score 0):

The default InputBox doesn't provide this validation functionality when enter the text. You'll have to create a window (input box) yourself and add the validation you want

The best option is to create a new Form with all validation for that 
text box you want and show it with `.ShowDialog()` to be modal like the InputBox

Answer (score 0):

I realize this has been answered already but there wasn't much given in way of example. I recently came across a similar issue attempting to validate an InputBox for only numeric input.

This is what I came up with, in regards to a Rainfall Statistics gathering application.

The loop is to collect rainfall amounts for each month.
I am passing the user input first in to a string, then validating the string using IsNumeric before converting to a double and assigning it to the current index in the array.

If the input is numeric it increments the loop counter to move on to the next month.

If not numeric it displays an error and loops again to ask for the same month input.

```
Private Sub ...

    Dim intMaxIndex As Integer = 11
    Dim strMonths() As String = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                                 "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}

    ' declare local array and counter
    Dim dblRainfallPerMonth(intMaxIndex) As Double
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    ' loop through the months
    Do Until i = intMaxIndex
        Dim strRainfall As String = ""
        ' get user input from InputBox and assign to a string
        strRainfall = InputBox("Enter the rainfall for " & strMonths(i))
        ' check if the user input is a number
        If IsNumeric(strRainfall) Then
            ' validation passed, convert user input and assign to current index in the array
            dblRainfallPerMonth(i) = CDbl(strRainfall)
            ' increment the counter
            i += 1
        Else
            ' validation failed, display error and do not increment the counter
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number")
        End If
      Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Dim str As String = InputBox(your message)

If IsNumeric(str) then

```
'numeric = true
```

Else

'type your error message

End if